# How to get better look for pie chart with big differences between y values?

Tags: asp.net, .net, charts, pie-chart

I am using asp.net pie chart for displaying data on my dashboard.

I have a big differences between Y values, for example:

High - 28820

Medium - 425

Low - 25537

The chart doesn't look good.

Is there a way to do something like ScaleBreakStyle to get a better look?

Thanks,
Inbal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you would use some third party tool for a good look

http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/pie-chart/index.html

is a better one in terms of look, working and flexibility...

many other similar to this are available....